# Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters. Error - for NPM Install Jest

Tags: terminal, jestjs, npm-install, ts-jest

Hello I am not sure what is wrong with installing Jest.

https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started

But here is my issue with my terminal. Please help. I am new to this.

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BCWM.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to run npm commands during `npm init` wizard.
Just press Ctrl+C to quit the wizard and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a request for confirmation. The failure you're seeing could be solved by pressing **return/enter** and confirming the name. After doing this you will see multiple details to be confirmed.